# Javascript multiple value object to simple array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
obj1 = {A: {bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}, B: {bottom: 30, mid: 23, top: 5}, C: {bottom: 41, mid: 25, top: 16}}
```

and I'm trying to convert to something like this:

```
obj2 = 
{group: "A", bottom: "63", mid: "4", top: "15"}
{group: "B", bottom: "30", mid: "23", top: "5"}
{group: "C", bottom: "41", mid: "25", top: "16"}
```

by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824076/convert-an-object-with-multiple-values-per-key-into-array-of-objects-in-js) but I'm getting an error `obj1[key].forEach is not a function` any ideas why I'm getting this error?

this is the code I'm using which is basically the same from the original:

```
obj1 ={A: {bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}, B: {bottom: 30, mid: 23, top: 5}, C: {bottom: 41, mid: 25, top: 16}}

const result = []

// for each key in obj
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
    // for each array element of the property obj[key]
    obj1[key].forEach((value, index) => {// in this line I'm getting the error
        // if an object doesn't exists at the current index in result
        // create it
        if (!result[index]) {
            result[index] = {}
        }
        // at the result index, set the key to the current value
        result[index][key] = value
    })
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: obj1["A"] returns an object - not an array - you can use object.entries instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because of this line `obj1[key].forEach((value, index)`, because it is an `object` and you are trying to use `forEach` on an object.

For example `obj1[key]` will give the value of `A` and `B` etc keys which as an object like `{bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}`.

You can us only `for..in` and then use destructing to push the values in the array

```js
const obj1 = {
  A: {
    bottom: 63,
    mid: 4,
    top: 15
  },
  B: {
    bottom: 30,
    mid: 23,
    top: 5
  },
  C: {
    bottom: 41,
    mid: 25,
    top: 16
  }
}

const result = []

for (let key in obj1) {
  result.push(Object.assign({}, obj1[key], {
    group: key
  }))

}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is available on arrays, but during the first iteration `obj1[key]` is effectively `obj1.A`, which returns an object `{bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}`, which doesn't have `forEach`, hence the error.

This might be a good use of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
obj1 = {A: {bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}, B: {bottom: 30, mid: 23, top: 5}, C: {bottom: 41, mid: 25, top: 16}}

const result = Object.entries(obj1).reduce(
  // group is the key from obj1, e.g. "A"
  // properties is the object for that key, e.g. { bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15 }
  (acc, [group, properties]) => [
    ...acc, { group, ...properties }
  ], []
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj1[key]` will return an object like `{bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}`, which doesnt have a `forEach` function. The simplest way to do what you are trying to do would be to add the group key to the object each loop and push it to results:

```
// for each key in obj
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
    obj1[key].group = key;
    result.push(obj1[key]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are trying to iterate through an object `obj1[key].forEach` which does not have a forEach function. the function belongs to  Array prototype.

Try this instead:

```
obj1 ={A: {bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}, B: {bottom: 30, mid: 23, top: 5}, C: {bottom: 41, mid: 25, top: 16}}

const result = []

// for each key in obj
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
    // for each array element of the property obj[key]
    Object.keys(obj1[key]).forEach((value, index) => {// in this line I'm getting the error
        // if an object doesn't exists at the current index in result
        // create it
        if (!result[index]) {
            result[index] = {}
        }
        // at the result index, set the key to the current value
        result[index][key] = value
    })
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a map function base on obj1's keys

```
    var obj1 = {A: {bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15}, B: {bottom: 30, mid: 23, top: 5}, C: {bottom: 41, mid: 25, top: 16}};

    var obj2 = Object.keys(obj1).map(function(k) {
      var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1[k])); // use lobash for cloning
      clone.group = k;
      return clone;
    });

    console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the keys using **Object.keys** and followed by using **.map** to form the required result

```js
var obj1 = {
  A: { bottom: 63, mid: 4, top: 15 },
  B: { bottom: 30, mid: 23, top: 5 },
  C: { bottom: 41, mid: 25, top: 16 }
};

var out = Object.keys(obj1).map(i => {
  return {
    group: i,
    ...obj1[i]
  };
});

console.log(out);
```